# Chrome tabs auto-switching, weird behaviour

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

so I have the following problems. If I have 10 tabs open in chrome and I work on the last one (which is at the right side) from time to time (randomly) Chrome will automatically change the tabs and we'll go through all of them (right to left) and it will stop at the first one (extreme left side).

Has anyone noticed this behaviour before?

Thanks

Comment: Same issue here on Ubuntu 21.10. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: no, still have the same issue.

Comment: what setup do you use? I have a Dell XPS 13 9310 laptop, and using a MX Master 2S wireless mouse.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it happened because of my wireless mouse. Somehow the port where it was connected to was causing the auto-switch of tabs. Try to change the USB port that you're using, that's what solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! It fiixed this very weird issue for me.

Comment: I thought it was a case of ghost in the machine -- thanks so much works for me too

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that when I move the mouse to the tab bar, it will sometimes start randomly moving the active tab